# Why is my NO RESULTS cell not displaying in my table view controller?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an app that has this cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TableViewCell *cell = nil;

    //IF NO STORES FOUND
    if ([self.annotationsToSort count] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"No results");
        cell.nameLabel.text = @"No results";
    }

    // Check to see whether the normal table or search results table is being displayed    
    //IF ITS A SEARCH TABLE....>>>>>>>>>
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"HolidayCell";
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        Location *location = [filteredResultsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.nameLabel.text = location.nombrePublico;

    } else {

    // IF ITS A REGULAR TABLE...>>>>>>>>>>
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"HolidayCell";
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            //cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
        }
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


        //USING SORTED ARRAY INSTEAD OF CDfetched ARRAY
        MyLocation *myLocation = [self.annotationsToSort objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.nameLabel.text = myLocation.name;
        cell.dateLabel.text =  myLocation.address;
        cell.distancia.text = distance;
        cell.phoneLabel.text = myLocation.telefono;
        cell.openLabel.text = myLocation.estado;
        cell.driveThruLabel.text = myLocation.driveThru;

    }
    return cell;
}
```

But even if there are no results in the data, it returns empty cells without my NO RESULTS text.  The rows method is:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [filteredResultsArray count];
    } else {
        //return [self.farSiman count]; WAS CRASHING
        return [self.annotationsToSort count];
    }

}
```

I already tried putting the NO STORES FOUND code block inside the NORMAL STATE TABLE if/else and that didnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `[self.annotationsToSort count]` is zero, then your `numberOfRowsInSection` method
returns zero, so that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not called at all, and an empty
table view is displayed.

If you want to display a special cell "No results", then you have to modify 
`numberOfRowsInSection` so that it returns `1` in that case.
For example, (untested, just to give you the idea):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if ([self.annotationsToSort count] == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [filteredResultsArray count];
    } else {
        return [self.annotationsToSort count];
    }
}
```

There are also some errors in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. For example,
no cell is allocated in the case `[self.annotationsToSort count] == 0`.
It should probably look more like this (again untested):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"HolidayCell";
    cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    //IF NO STORES FOUND
    if ([self.annotationsToSort count] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"No results");
        cell.nameLabel.text = @"No results";
    } else if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        Location *location = [filteredResultsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.nameLabel.text = location.nombrePublico;
    } else {
        MyLocation *myLocation = [self.annotationsToSort objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.nameLabel.text = myLocation.name;
        cell.dateLabel.text =  myLocation.address;
        cell.distancia.text = distance;
        cell.phoneLabel.text = myLocation.telefono;
        cell.openLabel.text = myLocation.estado;
        cell.driveThruLabel.text = myLocation.driveThru;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` is never being called in the situation you are looking for. If `[self.annotationsToSort count]` is 0 then it will not create any cells (so it will never call `cellForRowAtIndexPath`).

When it does call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` there are annotations so it obviously will not display your no results label. Also you are setting your cell to `nil` then attempting to set the label. So even if `cellForRowAtIndexPath` was called nothing would happen because your cell is nil! (You would actually get a crash due to this: `[self.annotationsToSort objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`).

A good work around is returning `1` in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` if there are no `annotationsToSort` so:

```
if (![self.annotationsToSort count]) {
    return 1;
}
```

Then in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TableViewCell *cell = nil;

    // Check to see whether the normal table or search results table is being displayed    
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        // your code //
    } else {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"HolidayCell";

        // you need to dequeue the cell first, then check if it is nil!
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            // other static cell configurations
        }

        if ([self.annotationsToSort count] == 0) {
            NSLog(@"No results");
            cell.nameLabel.text = @"No results";
        } else {
            // this line will crash your code if annotationsToSort is empty
            MyLocation *myLocation = [self.annotationsToSort objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            // configure cell with your code //
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it's can help you. try to add  return 1 ;  follow to code

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.


   if ([self.annotationsToSort count] == 0) 
    {
        return 1; 
    }
   else 
   { 
        return [self.annotationsToSort count];
   } 

}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 //IF NO STORES FOUND
    if ([self.annotationsToSort count] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"No results");
        cell.nameLabel.text = @"No results";
    }

    // Check to see whether the normal table or search results table is being displayed    
    //IF ITS A SEARCH TABLE....>>>>>>>>>
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"HolidayCell";
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        Location *location = [filteredResultsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.nameLabel.text = location.nombrePublico;

    } else {

    // IF ITS A REGULAR TABLE...>>>>>>>>>>
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"HolidayCell";
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            //cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
        }
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


        //USING SORTED ARRAY INSTEAD OF CDfetched ARRAY
        MyLocation *myLocation = [self.annotationsToSort objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.nameLabel.text = myLocation.name;
        cell.dateLabel.text =  myLocation.address;
        cell.distancia.text = distance;
        cell.phoneLabel.text = myLocation.telefono;
        cell.openLabel.text = myLocation.estado;
        cell.driveThruLabel.text = myLocation.driveThru;

    }
    return cell;

}
```